# pybind11 DLL load failed while importing

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, dll, pybind11

[possible lead I am too stupid to understand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61369141/importerror-dll-load-failed-with-pybind11-and-pcl)

I am trying to build a pybind11 module with CMake on Windows:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

void say_hello(){
    std::cout << "Hello, from c++!\n";
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {
    m.def("say_hello", &say_hello);
}
```

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.0)
project(example VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES C CXX)

find_package(Python COMPONENTS Interpreter Development REQUIRED)
find_package(pybind11 REQUIRED)

pybind11_add_module(example example.cpp)
```

`dumpbin /dependents build/example.cp311-win_amd64.pyd`

```
Dump of file build\example.cp311-win_amd64.pyd

File Type: DLL

  Image has the following dependencies:

    libgcc_s_seh-1.dll
    KERNEL32.dll
    msvcrt.dll
    libstdc++-6.dll
    python311.dll
```

```py
import example
example.say_hello()

# >>> ImportError: DLL load failed while importing example
```

What am I doing wrong? In case there is a solution to my problem, how can I make it reliable on other systems?

EDIT:
works flawlessly on linux, obv

Comment: `dumpbin` only list dependencies. It doesn't check whether they are found or not. Run the tool referenced in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61371168/3440745) and find out which dll cannot be found.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following line:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -static")
```

in the `CMakeLists.txt` file currently solves my problem on my Windows machine.
The `-static` flag tells the compiler to link the DLLs statically, meaning directly inside the .pyd binary file.

Most likely I had a problem with those DLLs dependencies...